# Jquery ui draggable lags on timelineMonth and tielineYear

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using full calendar scheduler and for dragging external events into the calendar I use this

```
$(this).draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    containment: 'window',
    appendTo:'body',
    scroll: false,
    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
    revertDuration: 0,  //  original position after the drag
    start: function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    },
    stop: function(){
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

when I am on basic week view and timeline day view it works ok, but when I am on timeline month and timeline year when I drag the external event it lags , why is this so?

this is how i populate events

```
    setTimeout(function(){

                        $.ajax({url: '/new/events',
                            type: 'POST',

                            success:function(response){
                                var events = [];

                                $.each(response,function(i,r){
                                    var fullname = r.eve.FirstName + " " + r.profile.LastName;
                                    var photo = r.eve.Photo;
                                    var gender = r.eve.Gender;
                                    $.each(r.data,function(j,calendar_data){
                                        events.push({
                                            id:calendar_data.id,
                                            fullName: fullname,
                                            start:moment(calendar_data.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                            end:moment(calendar_data.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                            photo:photo,
                                            gender:gender
                                        })
                                    });
                                });
                                cb(events);


                            error: function() {
                                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                            },
                            color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
                        });
   },0);
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is a lag because there is more data to load. It's probably not an issue with the jQuery you quote itself. How are you populating the calendar events?

Comment: @223seneca I added how I populate events

Comment: Can you provide a short screenshare of what happens when you are dragging?

Comment: I cant't at this moment, it just lags when on that views

Comment: It is because of to mutch events, but how can i solve this problem

Comment: what is the point of setTimeout when the timer value is 0? And anyway why would you want to delay this any further than the ajax already will? Also it's hard to see how that could be related to dragging external events. If you have too many events, that's not related to how you fetch the events. Can you determine, by testing, the quantity of events required to be on the calendar before this lagging begins to happen? Possibly it's just all the calculations needing to be done which cause this to happen. Without finding a way to optimise the fullCalendar source, I doubt you could influence that.

Comment: Also, JS performance can vary between browsers. What browser/OS/hardware spec(s) are you experiencing this on?

Comment: On chrome and firefox, set timeout  is only because i cant get the view name as a parameter, cause i need to send view name parameter to the api, only with set timeout I can do this

Comment: well you set your timeout to 0 so it's hard to see how it could make any difference to anything. And you don't use a view name within it, either, as far as I can see. Seems pointless.

Comment: Anyway you mention Chrome and Firefox, but which O/S and hardware? And what about other browsers? Do they perform ok?

Comment: All browsers the same